# Css issue on IPhone device for super expert?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

If you open http://docteur.tax on iphone 5 (or other version), you'll see a blank column on the right side (see screenshot below).

http://prntscr.com/c5wnfz

It seems something is reducing the width.
If you check at the footer module, you'll see there is a real problem; as footer suppose to be 100% width.

The big problem I have is I am not able to debg this with Jconsole as all the Iphone simulator borwsers don't shoz this issue. It appears only from a real mobile device.

I search hours on google how to check the code from iphone. But nothing worked.

I don't have Mac laptop and no SDK.

I need help of super expert who has the tools to check HTML code by Firebug or Jconsole from mobile.

Thanks in advance to the one who could help me.

Comment: Can you post your code or any site link ? So, anyone can help you.

Comment: Of course. here is the link: http://docteur.tax

Comment: The issue persists in a normal browser too. In chrome you can inspect the element and run it in smartphone mode. It's nearly as good as a phone. Your problem however is in bad markup, weird sizes etc. Check up on that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've hard-coded the width of this section.

```
.div_ebook {
  width:380px;
}
```

and the internal sections are set to be 50% of that.

Set this to 100% and it will always keep the page tight.

I was also able to see your issue using Google Chrome's Developer Tools to simulate an iPhone 5. You should be able to use that for further debugging.

Comment: Well... The problem is all the simulator show it correctly. But a real iphone (and maybe other smartphones) show the real bug.

Comment: @Nino please attach a screenshot of what it looks like on your real iPhone with the above updated code.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
.div_ebook {
    width: 380px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

That set width in pixels will be wider than Iphone 5 viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfourtunately it doesn't fix anything. There is something creating a bug in the css. And I can't check the elements and CSS from my iphone.

Comment: Have you tried setting that width to 300px? Iphone 5 is 320px wide, so do 300 and see if you still have the "bug".

Answer (score 0):

You could also install weinre (a bit old, but if you don't have other options...)